# Organizing point cloud from HDL-32E

Tags: velodyne, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

in order to accelerate the data processing on my HLD-32E I would like to organized the data. To this point, I could, under Octave, compute manually an point cloud. But I do actually have no idea how to implement it in C++ and the suggested functions, such as KDTree, don't seems to be fast enough for this task...

Is there somewhere a topic giving information about how to work with those Point clouds in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59743/organizing-point-cloud-from-hdl-32e/) by [Dexter111](https://answers.ros.org/users/4297/dexter111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-04-01

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using the ROS [velodyne](http://ros.org/wiki/velodyne) stack to provide the data?

If so, the [velodyne_pointcloud](http://ros.org/wiki/velodyne_pointcloud) package handles converting the raw data packets received from the device into ROS [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) messages. The HDL-32E spews out about 700,000 points per second in a highly permuted order, the HDL-64E provides about 1,000,000 points per second in a very different and less regular order. So, velodyne_pointcloud keeps things simpler by always producing "unordered" point clouds as the data arrive from the device.

To prevent that unordered representation from losing useful information, velodyne_pointcloud publishes its data using a custom PCL point definition: **velodyne_pointcloud::PointXYZIR**, defined in the [velodyne_pointcloud/point_types.h](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_pointcloud/include/velodyne_pointcloud/point_types.h) header. A **PointXYZIR** differs from the standard PCL **PointXYZI** (X, Y, Z, and intensity) in adding an additional field containing the "laser ring number" from which the point was measured.

Each ring number corresponds to a device-specific laser number, but the numbers are reordered so that ring 0 corresponds to the innermost laser (at the lowest angle) and ring 31 corresponds to the outermost laser (at the highest angle) of a 32E (that would be ring 63 on a 64E). That encoding ensures that adjacent lasers are labelled with adjacent ring numbers, which is not at all true of the hardware laser numbers. The actual mapping is defined in the [velodyne_driver/ring_sequence.h](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_driver/include/velodyne_driver/ring_sequence.h) header, provided by the velodyne_driver package. The permutation for a 32E is the same as the first 32 lasers of the 64E, so the same conversions work for both.

So, it should theoretically be possible to produce an ordered point cloud from the unordered PointXYZIR data by using the ring numbers as rows in a 2D representation. I have not heard of anyone actually doing that, and I suspect that the results might become somewhat confused when the device is in motion.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dexter111](https://answers.ros.org/users/4297/dexter111/) on 2013-07-03**:
Sorry for the long delay, but it could finaly organize the pointcloud and now I can segment and classify the point cloud in less than 0.2s ;)

**Comment by [kamek](https://answers.ros.org/users/3942/kamek/) on 2013-07-18**:
@Dexter111 Do you mind describing how you were able to do that? Did you use PCL at all?

**Comment by [orsonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28198/orsonl/) on 2016-10-23**:
Hi. I need the pointcloud from Velodyne VLP16. You mentioned that "velodyne_pointcloud publishes its data using a custom PCL point definition: velodyne_pointcloud::PointXYZIR". Do you mean that is a topic? After I do roslaunch "velodyne_pointclound VLP16_points.launch", nothing like that are found

**Comment by [orsonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28198/orsonl/) on 2016-10-24**:
For Velodyne VLP16, nothing like velodyne_pointcloud::PointXYZIR are published. Please tell me why

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-10-24**:
The topic name is `/velodyne_points`

**Comment by [claydergc](https://answers.ros.org/users/30525/claydergc/) on 2017-05-26**:
I don't know if this is still useful for you, but I wrote some code with PCL to organize a VLP16 point cloud and now I have a 16xN point cloud. I am still doing some tests, but you can find my code here: https://github.com/claydergc/vlp16_pointcloud/blob/master/src/vlp16_cloud.cpp

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2019-03-07**:
@claydergc, did you ever get that code fully functional? I've tried it out but haven't been able to get it working so far.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**TL;DR:** Use the function I wrote here:  [organize_velodyne_cloud](https://github.com/msy22/organize_velodyne_cloud)

I had to solve this problem recently in order to use the cloud for mesh creation with the Point Cloud Library (PCL). At the time I couldn't find anyone else who had solved this problem, so I had to write the code myself following the suggestions here from @joq. I've added to core functions to the repo linked above, as they're a bit too long to put here. Hopefully this will save anyone after me ~1-2 weeks effort.

How it works is this: every Velodyne LiDAR unit fires its lasers in a pre-defined sequence that repeats. E.g. 0, 16, 1, 17, 2, 18... But not every laser beam returns to the unit, so some parts of the cloud need to be filled in with points whose coordinates are `NaN` to preserve the organized nature of the cloud. My function creates a 2D organized cloud where there is one row for each "ring" of velodyne data. It then fills in each row, tracking how many points are in each row, i.e. what "column" of data is currently being filled in. When it moves from one column of data to the next, it fills in any gaps with `NaN` points.

Be careful how you use the organized cloud after this, as some PCL functions will crash if you input a cloud with `NaN`s, or worse, silently destroy the organized nature of the cloud without warning you.

---

Originally posted by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) with karma: 2327 on 2019-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-28**:
@M@t: would this be something to contribute to some more visible package? I'm thinking `laser_filters` or something similar, but then for lidars. Perhaps even the velodyne package itself?

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2019-03-28**:
That might certainly be a good idea, the velodyne package would be the best fit as the function depends on the specific operation of Velodyne LiDARs. How time consuming is that process likely to be? Unfortunately I have precious little spare time right now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-28**:
re: time: no idea. I'd suggest just opening an issue on the velodyne tracker and seeing whether there is any interest.